# Get the contents of a .NET Array (e.g. byte[]) in a visual studio package

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-extensions

I'm writting a Visual Studio Extension to inspect certain data types in the Visual Studio Debugger. 
For this matter I would like to examine the contents of a large .NET array, e.g. a byte[] array. But I am struggeling on how to this efficiently.
What I have so far is that I registered my class to receive DebugEvents and store the last
thread everytime an event occurs:

```
IVsDebugger debugService =  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsShellDebugger)) as IVsDebugger;
debugService.AdviseDebugEventCallback(this);
...
public int Event(IDebugEngine2 pEngine, IDebugProcess2 pProcess, IDebugProgram2 pProgram, IDebugThread2 pThread, IDebugEvent2 pEvent, ref Guid riidEvent, uint dwAttrib)
{
  lastThread = pThread;
}
```

To inspect an object I dervive the Stackframe from the lastThread Object and obtain an IDebugExpressionContext2 from the Stackframe. Assuming there is an Oject called test wich has a byte[] proberty Matrix, I do the following

```
IDebugExpression2 expression;
string error;
uint errorCharIndex;

epressionContext.ParseText("test.Matrix", (enum_PARSEFLAGS.PARSE_EXPRESSION), 10, 
                           out expression, out error, out errorCharIndex);
IDebugProperty2 debugProperty = null;
expression.EvaluateSync(enum_EVALFLAGS.EVAL_NOSIDEEFFECTS,1000, null, out 
                        debugProperty);

DEBUG_PROPERTY_INFO[] info = new DEBUG_PROPERTY_INFO[1];
debugProperty.GetPropertyInfo(enum_DEBUGPROP_INFO_FLAGS.DEBUGPROP_INFO_ALL, 0, 1000,
                             null, 0, info);
```

This all works fine and the info structure contains reasonable values. But if I try to get a IDebugMemoryByte2 object to read the contents of the byte[] array, I receive null.

```
IDebugMemoryContext2 memoryContext;
debugProperty.GetMemoryContext(out memoryContext);
IDebugMemoryBytes2 memoryBytes;
debugProperty.GetMemoryBytes(out memoryBytes);
```

I could traverse the DEBUG_PROPERTY_STRUCTURE and read every single element of the array but this would be way too slow. So whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at the return value of debugProperty.GetMemoryBytes? I have called it for a string object and received 0x80004001 (not Implemented)